# Process.nextTick and Promise callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop

when I run

```
    process.nextTick(() => console.log(8)) 
    Promise.resolve("hi").then(t => console.log(t)) 
    console.log(7); 
    
    Output is 7 8 hi
```

The output is expected  because process.nextTick runs after the stack is empty and before we start processing the task queue. But when I run

```
function main() {

  console.log(1);
  console.log(2);
  func();
  console.log(6);
}

function func() {
  console.log(4);
  console.log(5);
  Promise.resolve() // callback gets pushed to microtask queue
  .then(() => { // this callback is in callstack now after logging 6
      process.nextTick(() => console.log(8)) 
      Promise.resolve("hi").then(t => console.log(t)) 
      console.log(7); 
  })
}
Output is 1 2 4 5 6 7 hi 8
```

Why does the last part log 7 hi 8 instead of 7 8 hi?

Comment: Just to let you know that this level of detail in the relative scheduling priorities should not be relied upon in your normal coding.  If you care about the sequencing of operations to this level, then write the code to require them to run in a particular order (typically with chained promises).  And, while a lot of deep diving into things could actually explain your observations here, it will not actually turn out to be useful in your programming.  I've answered quite a number of these before, but decided to avoid them now because in the end, it is not actually useful to your programming.

Comment: Relevant reading: [Promises, nextTick and setImmedaite](https://blog.insiderattack.net/promises-next-ticks-and-immediates-nodejs-event-loop-part-3-9226cbe7a6aa).  There have been implementation changes through the nodejs versions in this regard, so it also matters what version of nodejs you're running (yet another reason why you shouldn't rely on this level of scheduling detail in your programming).

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you are adding promise callbacks (microtasks) recursively.

Promise callbacks are microtasks, and they are added to the microtasks queue managed by v8.

When v8 executes the microtasks queue it will find your first resolved promise callback as the only microtask in the queue. But when v8 executes the callback, another microtask is immediately added to the queue by `Promise.resolve("hi").then(t => console.log(t))`. Since v8 is still processing microtasks, it will process the second promise resolve callback before moving on.

This will become quite clear if you schedule another microtask inside your second `Promise.resolve` callback as follows:

```js
function main() {

  console.log(1);
  console.log(2);
  func();
  console.log(6);
}

function func() {
  console.log(4);
  console.log(5);
  Promise.resolve() // callback gets pushed to microtask queue
  .then(() => { // this callback is in callstack now after logging 6
      process.nextTick(() => console.log(8)) 
      Promise.resolve("hi").then(t => {
        console.log(t)
        Promise.resolve("there").then(t => console.log(t))
      }) 
      console.log(7); 
  })
}
```

The above code will yield the following output:

```
1
2
4
5
6
7
hi
there
8
```

[I wrote the article series](https://blog.insiderattack.net/promises-next-ticks-and-immediates-nodejs-event-loop-part-3-9226cbe7a6aa) linked by @jfriend00 (Thanks for linking the article). However, this behaviour you observed is consistent across all NodeJS versions. (at least currently stable Node versions at the time of this writing.)

Scheduling microtasks recursively is risky, and it's [documented in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide).

> Warning: Since microtasks can themselves enqueue more microtasks, and the event loop continues processing microtasks until the queue is empty, there's a real risk of getting the event loop endlessly processing microtasks. Be cautious with how you go about recursively adding microtasks.

Answer (score 1):

Callback function passed to the `process.nextTick` is invoked asynchronously and is executed *after* the current operation has finished.

In your case, the *current operation* is the processing of the micro-task queue. Once the processing of the micro-task queue is started, it continues until all the micro-tasks in the queue have been processed.

Any micro-tasks enqueued by the existing micro-tasks in the micro-task queue are also processed, which can lead to infinite loop if you are not careful.

In the following code

```
Promise.resolve() 
 .then(() => { 
     process.nextTick(() => console.log(8)) 
     Promise.resolve("hi").then(t => console.log(t)) 
     console.log(7); 
 })
```

after scheduling the callback passed to `process.nextTick`, current micro-task (callback function of `then()`) queues another micro-task:

```
Promise.resolve("hi").then(t => console.log(t))
```

This micro-task will also be processed in the current phase of processing the micro-task queue.

Once the micro-tasks have been processed, event loop will process the callback function passed to the `process.nextTick` before moving to the next phase of processing different callbacks in different queues.

For further details, see: [The Node.js Event Loop, Timers, and process.nextTick()](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/)